# TypeError: CryptoJS.SHA256 is not a function

Tags: javascript, hash, cryptojs, sha

```js
import * as CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';
import * as ecdsa from 'elliptic';
import * as _ from 'lodash'

class Transaction {
    id = null;
    constructor(id, txIns, txOuts) {
        this.id = id;
        this.txIns = txIns;
        this.txOuts = txOuts;
    }
}

function getTransactionId (Transaction)
{
    const txInContent = Transaction.txIns.txOutId + Transaction.txIns.txOutIndex;
//    const txInContent = Transaction.TxIN.map((TxIN) => TxIN.txOutId + TxIN.txOutIndex).reduce((a, b) => a + b, '');
    const txOutContent = Transaction.txOuts.amount + Transaction.txOuts.address;
//    const txOutContent = Transaction.TxOut.map((TxOUT) => txOut.amount + txOut.address).reduce((a, b) => a + b, '');

    return (txInContent + txOutContent).toString();
}


class TxIN {
    txOutId = null;
    txOutIndex = null;
    signature = null;

    constructor(txOutId, txOutIndex, signature) {
        this.txOutId = txOutId;         // Previous transaction ID
        this.txOutIndex = txOutIndex;
        this.signature = signature;     // Sender's signature
    }
}

class TxOUT {
    amount = null;
    address = null;

    constructor(amount, address) {
        this.amount = amount;     // Amount value of output
        this.address = address;   // Receiver's address
    }
}

let testOut = new TxOUT(10, "tb1****************************ntxt");

let testIn = new TxIN("tb******************************tntxt", 0, "gg")

let testTrans = new Transaction("1329***********************1e99ba8", testIn, testOut);


var test = 'GG';

console.log(test);
var t = CryptoJS.SHA256(test);
```

I am using the CryptoJS.SHA256() on my JavaScript project. But is shows the "TypeError: CryptoJS.SHA256 is not a function". And I've already import the 'crypto-js'. When I tried to log the crypto. I found the "SHA256: [Function (anonymous)]". But the TypeError cannot be solved.
Is there something I make a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try these :

`npm install @types/node --save-dev`
to install NodeJS definitions

```
npm install --save @types/crypto-js
```

In tsconfig.ts file add the following:

```
"files": [
"./node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts"
]
```

Import the library where you want to use it with import

```
import * as sha256 from 'crypto-js/sha256';
```

or
with speical import syntax

```
import sha256 = require("crypto-js/sha256");
```

Comment: It still not working... Shows "TypeError: sha256 is not a function" again.

Comment: Is that a typescript project, Angular ? or plain javascript ?

Comment: It is a plain javascript project

Comment: I solved the problem, thanks for help!

Comment: cool. Can you let us know , what was the problem as well

Comment: I run the command "npm install --save @types/crypto-js" in terminal and then it works.

Comment: ok, Please accept the answer also if you found that useful

Answer (score 0):

try to get it like this:

```
var SHA256 = require("crypto-js/sha256");
console.log(SHA256('my message'));
```

here is running demo:
https://replit.com/@slash851/crypto-js-test#index.js